# C# Prevent Spawned Process From Inheriting Existing Process's PID

Tags: c#, excel, windows, process

I need to spawn MS Excel from my C# code to open a spreadsheet, then I need to do a WaitForExit() with this spawned process to continue after the user closes the Excel Window. This doesn't work if there is already an existing Excel window open.

Here is the timeline:

1)
I open an Excel window, this process has PID X.

2)
I run my code, which spawns another Excel process to display my file:

```
var excelProcess = new Process();
excelProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\Program Files\Office\Excel.exe";
excelProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = "myFile.xlsx";
excelProcess.Start();
Console.WriteLine(excelProcess.Id); //This will print PID Y
excelProcess.WaitForExit();
//Code to be run when user closes Excel
```

3. 

A new Excel window opens file "myFile.xlsx". Both windows are still open, but the code that is after the call to WaitForExit() starts executing.

4)
I look at the PIDs in the Task Manager, and see one running Excel process with PID X. Mind you, the process I started had PID Y, which is no longer alive.

Conclusion:
When I open my file, the spawned Excel process is "merged" into the one that was already running and inherits its PID. So, as far as my code is concerned the process has ended and it can continue since there is no process with PID Y. This is probably a feature in Excel and/or Windows to keep the number of open processes down.
Note: The WaitForEnd works as I intended if I don't open the first Excel window in step 1.

Question:
Is it possible to stop my spawned process from inheriting the existing PID? I want there to be 2 separate Excel processes with different PIDs. I would think it would be either a command line option for Excel or something in the Process.StartInfo . I'm sure that I can get around this by just checking if the file is open by the filename, but this is an interesting problem and the solution might be useful for other applications.

Comment: It isn't "inheriting". The default for Office programs is to open a single process that edits multiple files (MS calls them instances). Change your arguments to excel to use the `/X` switch to force a separate instance / process. (NOTE: This could causes user prompts complaining about personal.xlsx or any XLSTART workbooks already being locked for writing.)

Comment: You can use the excel object model to open the file and then wait for the BeforeClose event to tell you that the workbook is closing. This makes you independent of the process model.